# Unexplainable 403 error "User not allow to perform the action" in Keyrock

Tags: http-status-code-403, fiware, fiware-keyrock

I've been struggling for a while with this issue and wondered if anyone else had the same problem.

I've got a **Keyrock 7.8.0** + MySQL architecture running with docker as FIWARE tutorials suggest. I can access both GUI and API through localhost:3005. Everything seems to work fine through GUI with admin user but when it comes to granting, **with admin Auth-Token**, a role to a user

```curl
curl -X PUT \
  http://localhost:3005/v1/applications/20f9bc1d-a9d1-45af-bdd9-f96fdc7a1ec9/users/c8336e47-8e3b-4081-b0f7-b2a3431847d7/roles/55e8a41c-52b5-4ef9-ad9c-ef60762d32e3 \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 0' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Cookie: session=eyJyZWRpciI6Ii8ifQ==; session.sig=TqcHvLKCvDVxuMk5xVfrKEP-GSQ' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:3005' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: cb7e8ae3-87b4-4d8e-9fb7-a66ef439a7cf,7f736505-8c7e-4991-8449-ebd6e54714f7' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0' \
  -H 'X-Auth-token: f20c72c6-7c2a-4d8e-8d48-568e1c4e47d6' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

or an organization,

```curl
curl -X PUT \
  http://localhost:3005/v1/applications/20f9bc1d-a9d1-45af-bdd9-f96fdc7a1ec9/organizations/d98534f7-ecaa-4c38-93cc-c17d87f010ee/roles/55e8a41c-52b5-4ef9-ad9c-ef60762d32e3/organization_roles/member \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 0' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Cookie: session=eyJyZWRpciI6Ii8ifQ==; session.sig=TqcHvLKCvDVxuMk5xVfrKEP-GSQ' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:3005' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 11fc3dbb-8484-482f-8bc1-af89dcdeebb5,8bfdcdb5-f200-4bee-bcee-a8f6d83b18f0' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0' \
  -H 'X-Auth-token: f20c72c6-7c2a-4d8e-8d48-568e1c4e47d6' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

it just responds with this error in the body:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "User not allow to perform the action",
        "code": 403,
        "title": "Forbidden"
    }
}
```

Anyone knows how can it be that the same user has permission to do a thing through the GUI and not through the API?

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same issue and probably found a solution:

> According to the documentation for assigning roles to organizations or
>   for assigning roles to users, the HTTP verb PUT must be used. In
>   reality, Keyrock then responds with the following error message:
>
> ```
> { 
>    "error": {
>       "message": "User not allow to perform the action",
>       "code": 403,
>       "title": "Forbidden"   
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> When we use the HTTP verb POST instead of PUT, the role is assigned
>   successfully to the organization/user.
>
> Therefore, we assume that either the documentation or the
>   implementation is faulty.

Source: https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/issues/144

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Florian. I will try again with keyrock and see if your suggestion works.